# Как сверстать элемент более простым способом?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Знаю что модно сделать такое через clip: rect(); 
Но есть ли более простой способ?

Comment: Покажите пример, как clip:rect() режет такое.

Comment: На сайте, с которого был сделан скриншот, как это реализовано?

Comment: Своим пятым голосом я закрываю вопрос, потому что от вопроса-картинки очень мало толку и такие вопросы не ищутся в поисковиках. Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос словесным описанием того, что именно вы хотите

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/380);
  background-size: cover;
}

.header {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 20% 100%, transparent 20%, mediumpurple 20%);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
}

.pic {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/180/180);
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="pic"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Головааа... Ну ты умница...... Класс, мне понравилось...  Не знаю как с поддержкой, но в целом супер...